# STM32 - Extremely large .bin file

Tags: c, linker, embedded, stm32, stm32cubeide

Good day!

I work in a safety critical field and I'm having trouble with building in CubeIDE.

**Backstory**
Being safety critical, my company requires some redundant CRC in our code section of flash. We set aside a small portion of flash for non-CRC data (the numerical value of our code section CRC value, firmware revision, etc.) then have a post build batch file that calls a python script that calculates the initial CRC value of our code section which is then stored in the non-CRC section. In runtime, the CRC value is occasionally computed from flash and compared to the initial CRC value.

**The Problem**
I'm porting the source code from a similar product over to the new version of the firmware for a different product (moving from an 8-bit to a 32-bit STM32 uC). The ported code compiles fine and flashes/runs on the uC, but the .bin file that the CRC value is calculated from is massive at nearly 400Mb. The .bin file for the similar product's firmware is 32kb. In the large .bin file, there are about 399Mb of 0xFF's from the end of "flash memory" to the end of the file. As such, a calculation of the CRC value would not be valid.

**What I've Tried**
I'm still a baby developer, so I don't have much experience in troubleshooting these things. Looking at the .elf files for both projects, I noticed that the project with the massive .bin file has a fundamental difference from the other .elf file. The VMA and LMA for the .data section are identical in the .elf file for the new project and different for the similar project (with a VMA in the RAM section and an LMA in the FLASH section.

I've done research into LD (the GNU linker language) and understand that the NOLOAD flag is *supposed* to cause a section to not be loaded into memory, but putting that flag on the .data section doesn't have any effect. The linker files for both projects are identical for the .data section, so I'm not sure why their addressing would differ.

Here is the code for the .data section from the linker file:

```
/* Initialized data sections into RAM memory */
.data : 
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
} > RAM AT > CODE_FLASH
```

*RAM is at `0x2000 0000` and CODE_FLASH is at `0x0800 0000` (approximately.. it's just after a small VTABLE and the non-CRC section of flash).

What I believe is happening is that, even though there's nothing to put in the .data section (SIZE is 0), because it's LMA is at RAM, the .bin file is filled with 0xFF's up to that point, then nothing else. I just don't know how to fix it.

I've attached a (Notepad++ diff'd) screenshot of the sections from objdump.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

[image: diff between objdump section headers]

Comment: I assume .bin file is created from ELF with objcopy. 0xFFs fill gap between sections. You can extract sections to separate files, concatenate them in order as they are stored in flash and calculate its CRC.

Comment: The program used to create the .bin file is appending 399 MB of blank flash (0xFF) from the end of your flash section (0x0800????) to the beginning of your RAM section (0x20000000).  Read the manual to see if there is a way to remove that extra blank space from the .bin file.  Or check out the [srec_cat](https://srecord.sourceforge.net/) tool, which lets you do all sorts of manipulations of .bin and .hex files.

Comment: you need read more about linker and carefully handle the section (especially .text and .data). Normally, the bin should contains only .text part and the data should be copy from the text later.

Comment: `.data` should not be in the flash or checked with the CRC.   The init code should unpack the initial values of `.data` from `.rodata` (you can see this with the LMA on your old project).   If you're writing your own bootloader, though, you can use your "new" layout and not have the startup code unpack the `.data` because your bootloader populates the ram directly.

Comment: (Just to be sure, many toolchains do it a little different or call things a little different.  basically, you want the init 'version' of .data that's at the LMA in the flash and ignore the stuff that's at the VMA unless you're writing your own bootloader.)